# Installing Avira Antivirus on Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, anti-virus, avira

I have a licence of Avira and recently I switched to Windows 8 but apparently I cannot install the Avira on Windows 8.  Has anyone managed to install Avira on Windows 8 and how?

Comment: What exact edition and version of Avria are you trying to use?

Comment: I have a key from my uni for Avira AntiVir Professional 10.2

Comment: I would not bother installing another anti-virus on Windows 8, it is already included in the OS.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [Avira's website](http://www.avira.com/en/support-for-home-knowledgebase-detail/kbid/1385):

> Currently, the Avira products are not ready for Windows 8 and Windows Server 2012 (Built on Windows 8).
>
> Avira is working closely with Microsoft to achieve compatibility for the products as soon as possible.
> Therefore, it can be said with certainty that the Avira products will be compatible with Windows 8 in the first quarter of 2013.

This same information should be shown to you when you click the "Check for solutions online" button after it fails to install on Windows 8 [[source](http://www.avira.com/en/windows8-compatibility)].

Answer (score 5):

Avira is simply not compatible with Windows 8 at this time.

They also have put up a [notice regarding this](http://www.avira.com/en/support-for-business-knowledgebase-detail/kbid/1385) on their website.